# Android Single Spinner, Multiple Arrays

Tags: android, spinner

I haven't been able to find the answer to this anywhere (it's quite possible I'm not searching right). In Android I'm trying to make a single spinner in my app pull from multiple arrays depending on which radio button is selected. If radio button 1 is selected I want the spinner to use array 1, if radio button 2 is selected I want the spinner to use array 2. Here is what I have so far, but it doesn't work. Everytime I click on the tab in my app with this code my app force closes.

```
public class This_Activity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

private RadioButton rb1;
private RadioButton rb2;
private RadioButton rb3;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tab_2_layout);
    rb1=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.Radio1);
    rb2=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.Radio2);
    rb3=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.Radio3);}{




    if(rb1.isChecked() == true){

        Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.Array1, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    if(rb2.isChecked() == true){

        Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.Array2, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    if(rb3.isChecked() == true){

        Spinner spinner3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.Array3, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner3.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


}
```

}

Comment: check your Log and post here that why your app got force close

Comment: rb3=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.Radio3);}{ .. remove "}{" and also, this has nothing to do with it, but anyways: rb1.isChecked() == true will always return true, so write instead rb1.isChecked()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to diagnose the problem without the error messages you are seeing. Could you edit your question and include those?

However, one thing I am noticing is that you are creating different spinners in each of those cases. Try using

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = null;
```

above your if statements. Then the body of your if statements will look like

```
adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
        this, R.array.Array1, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

you also probably want to hook up listeners to your radio buttons to change the spinner automatically when the user clicks on them, because as it is now this will only happen in the constructor.

```
    rb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // change your spinner adapter here
        }
    });
```

it is probably easier to put your radio buttons in a [RadioGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html) and put the OnCheckChangedListener on that, so you only need one listener for all 3 buttons.